# SQLite: detect if a rowid exists

Tags: sql, sqlite

What's the best/right/fastest/most appropriate way to detect if a row with a given rowid exists?

Or by extension, hwo to detect if at least one row matching a given condition exists?

I'm firing quite some of these requests. I am currently using

```
SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1
```

looks a bit weird to me, but looks to me like "the least work" for the db, however, my SQL knowledge is spotty.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do it something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM table1 WHERE ID=someid)
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```

To `Count` the rows is not that effective.

To check if something `exists` is in most cases more effective

Comment: I don't necessarily need a 0/1, a SELECT Where sqlite3_step() returns DONE or ROW would be enough.  --

Answer (score 2):

Since it's sqlite, you need to use the column name "rowid" to access that id column.  Using Craig Ringer's sql, the sqlite version would look like this:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE rowid = insert_number)
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, 'rowid' is a specific column in all SQLite tables unless WITHOUT ROWID is specified during table creation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS`, it sounds perfect for what you are after. e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.X = T1.X AND T2.Y = 1)
```

It is effectly the same as `LIMIT 1` but is generally optimised better.

Comment: Hypothetic Table names, and X and Y are column names. It was just to demonstrate the `EXISTS` Clause and how you can reference the outer table from within the `EXISTS` Subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ID = whatever
```

Comment: You're better off with `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ID = whatever` or, if SQLite supports it, `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = whatever)` for a boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

One could test

```
select true from table where id = id1
```